# initialize two dimensional string array with dynamic size in java

Tags: java, dynamic-arrays

I have unknown number of records and I need to put all that records in string two dimensional array.

I don't know the number of records and due to this, don't know number of rows and columns which is required for string 2d array initialization.

Currently I am using as below:

```
String[][] data = new String[100][100];
```

Here I hard coded number of rows and columns but need something dynamic size allowable in string 2d array. Any suggestion pls!

Rgrds

Comment: Have you considered the Java collection framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following class which stores your data in a `HashMap` and is able to convert it to a two dimensional string array.

```
public class ArrayStructure {
    private HashMap<Point, String> map = new HashMap<Point, String>();
    private int maxRow = 0;
    private int maxColumn = 0;

    public ArrayStructure() {
    }

    public void add(int row, int column, String string) {
        map.put(new Point(row, column), string);
        maxRow = Math.max(row, maxRow);
        maxColumn = Math.max(column, maxColumn);
    }

    public String[][] toArray() {
        String[][] result = new String[maxRow + 1][maxColumn + 1];
        for (int row = 0; row <= maxRow; ++row)
            for (int column = 0; column <= maxColumn; ++column) {
                Point p = new Point(row, column);
                result[row][column] = map.containsKey(p) ? map.get(p) : "";
            }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Example code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayStructure s = new ArrayStructure();
    s.add(0, 0, "1");
    s.add(1, 1, "4");

    String[][] data = s.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j)
            System.out.print(data[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1  
 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply initialize with a literal, empty two-dimensional array:

```
String[][] data = new String[][]{{}}
```

Comment: I am getting exception in console: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 when try to put data in data array!

Comment: You need to initialize each dimension with your dynamic data and its size. If you don't want to do that, consider using a `Map<String, List<String>>` instead, it'll let you use real dynamic sizing.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarely store them in a `List<String[]>` and use `List#toArray(String[])` to convert it to a two dimensional array.

**Example**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
            "data.txt")));

    String line;
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
        list.add(line.split(" +"));

    String[][] data = new String[list.size()][];
    list.toArray(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j)
            System.out.print(data[i][j]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    r.close();
}
```

**Data.txt**

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 5 3
2  5  5 8
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 5 3
2 5 5 8
```

Comment: thanks 4 ur answer! but, I am storing CSV data in array something like in ith row and nth column, this will be value and in jth row and n+12th column that will be value. as like- str2dArr[i][n]="hi",str2dArr[j][n+12]="hello".   In this case, your answer may not work. Is it?      I know if I use List<String[]> and at last I can use toArray for getting String[][] but here I require just opposite! Any suggestion!

Comment: in that case, no... If you need to be able to dynamically add stuff to the two dimensional array, than this approach will not work.

Comment: @SSingh see my second answer to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    // create the object
    String[][] data;

    // ----- dinamically know the matrix dimension ----- //
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int r = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    int c = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    // ------------------------------------------------ //

    // allocate the object
    data = new String[r][c];

    // init the object
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            data[i][j] = "hello";
}
```

In this example you know the matrix dimension runtime, specifying it manually via the console.