# Trying to create a 2d array based on given rows from user input (java)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So this is what I have so far.

```
public static int[][] generateRandomPositions(int number, int width, int height){

    for(int j=0; j <number; j++){
         int[][] pos = new int[][]{
             {Utility.randomInt(width),Utility.randomInt(height)}

         };

    }

    return [][]pos;
}
```

Basically the method gets a number which is the number of rows there should be and the width and height is the two numbers that will be in the two columns. Those of which are randomly generated between the number given (ex Utility.randomInt(5) would be between 0 and 5). The problem I am having is figuring out how to create the number of rows based off the number that is inputted. What I have I don't believe works. This is an example of what the out come should be if these numbers were inputted.

```
generateRandomPositions(4, 5, 30)
int[][] posB = new int[][] {
{ 3,21 }, 
{ 4,15 },
{ 1,17 }
{ 3,9 }
};
```

There are 4 rows because 4 was inputted as the number. The other numbers were randomly generated. So I just need help figuring out how to create the number of rows based off the numbers variable inputted. I am fairly new to programming so and suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need read up on how to create arrays in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: I understand how to create arrays I just don't know how to create one when there is a different possible amount of rows based on what is put into the method.

Comment: Seriously?  Does Google not work for you?  Here's the first hit I get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array  Just replace the number with a variable name.

Comment: Here's a more direct answer.  Again, Google is your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939594/initialize-two-dimensional-string-array-with-dynamic-size-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [initialize two dimensional string array with dynamic size in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939594/initialize-two-dimensional-string-array-with-dynamic-size-in-java)

Comment: Right so I would do int[][] posB = new int[number][2] but then how would I get those random numbers in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int[][] generateRandomPositions(int number, int width, int height){
    int[][] pos = new int[number][2];
    for(int j=0; j <number; j++){
       pos[j][0] = Utility.randomInt(width);
       pos[j][1] = Utility.randomInt(height);
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, 2d arrays just really confuse the heck out of me.